# Can you reference 'this' class as a generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I have had a bit of a problem a few times where I want to do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public Validator<this.class> getValidator();
}

class MyInstance implements MyInterface
{
     public Validator<this.class> getValidator()
     {
          //do stuff
     }
}
```

So to be able to pass a reference to the concrete class as a generic parameter, it is often needed when you have classes that act on the current class. A simple solution is to use the ? type, but it's not ideal when you then need to access values in the class itself (eg. if you needed to do something like `getValidator().validateForm().getField()`)  or even if you want to subclass a class with chained methods (like the `StringBuilder.append()`)

The way I have usually had to do it like this:

```
interface MyInterface<T>
{
    public Validator<T> getValidator();
}

class MyInstance implements MyInterface<MyInstance>
{
     public Validator<MyInstance> getValidator()
     {
          //do stuff
     }
}
```

but that is quite ugly, and it is easy to accidentally put the wrong class as the parameter.

Are there any other solutions to this one?

---

**Edit:** The answers provided by 'Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?' currently do not solve this problem (apart from the Scala answer)

Comment: I'm not sure what `this.class` is supposed to represent. Is it supposed to represent `Class<MyInterface>`? I'm not understanding your problem

Comment: I mean that it should reference the concrete class that extends the MyInterface, so in this case it should end up being MyInstance, but if another class(say AnotherInstance), extended MyInterface, the `getValidator()` would return a Validator<AnotherInstance>

Comment: as mentioned before this also is a problem for chained methods, so imagine you wanted to extend StringBuilder as a new class `ErrorBuilder`, and add another chained method, let's say `appendError()`, if you do `new ErrorBuilder().appendError("Error").append("Here")` that would work fine, as `appendError()` would return a class of `ErrorBuilder` however if you did `new ErrorBuilder().append("Here").appendError("Error")` it would fail, as append returns a StringBuilder! It would be ideal if you could have a signature like `public this.class append(String x)`

Comment: The answers do not solve the problem, as it is not possible to solve your problem. What you want is not type-safe in the Java type system. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's any other way than your "usual" to get exactly what you're after.

However, as an alternative, you might consider consider:

```
interface MyInterface {
    Validator<? extends MyInterface> getValidator();
}
```

where `MyInterface` also defines the accessor methods needed by validators. (Note that `MyInstance`'s implementation could still return a `Validator<MyInstance>`.)

The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) might be another way to alter the design to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

The reason is the same reason that you cannot assign a `List<Dog>` to a `List<Animal>`.

If what you want is possible, you could have an implementation:

```
class MyInstance implements MyInterface
{
     public Validator<MyInstance> getValidator()
```

However, in your interface, the return type of `getValidator()` was 'defined' as `Validator<MyInterface>` (since `this.class` referred to `MyInterface` in the context of the interface)

And you cannot assign `Validator<MyInstance>` to `Validator<MyInterface>`.

The reason for that is that, if you could do that, you could have another class that returns a `Validator<MyOtherInstance>` which you could also assign to `Validator<MyInterface>`. And when you then try to call methods on `Validator<MyInstance>`, you don't now whether it was one that was taking `MyInstance` or `MyOtherInstance` objects.